# Agora's Video call black screen

Tags: java, android, agora.io, videocall

I do every thing in this repository but the code did not work with me and the camera appear black 
any one can help me ?

(https://github.com/digitallysavvy/android-video-chat-demo)

this is the output

https://ibb.co/ZmgnBRB

this is logcat

```
05-23 00:46:04.903 7292-7312/com.example.android.myagoraapplication 
W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/evrc
05-23 00:46:04.913 7292-7312/com.example.android.myagoraapplication 
W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/qcelp
05-23 00:46:04.943 7292-7312/com.example.android.myagoraapplication 
W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
05-23 00:46:04.953 7292-7312/com.example.android.myagoraapplication 
W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/mpeg-L1
05-23 00:46:04.953 7292-7312/com.example.android.myagoraapplication 
W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/mpeg-L2
05-23 00:46:04.963 7292-7312/com.example.android.myagoraapplication 
W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/x-ima
05-23 00:46:04.963 7292-7312/com.example.android.myagoraapplication 
W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/qcelp
05-23 00:46:04.963 7292-7312/com.example.android.myagoraapplication 
W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/evrc
05-23 00:46:04.983 7292-7312/com.example.android.myagoraapplication 
W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile/level 32768/2 for video/mp4v-es
05-23 00:46:05.013 7292-7312/com.example.android.myagoraapplication 
W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/mp4v-esdp
05-23 00:46:05.033 7292-7312/com.example.android.myagoraapplication 
I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
05-23 00:46:05.033 7292-7312/com.example.android.myagoraapplication 
W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
05-23 00:46:05.033 7292-7312/com.example.android.myagoraapplication 
W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
```

Comment: same for me too. Any luck?

Comment: What version of the Agora SDK are you using? this project is setup with an older version of the SDK so it may need updated.